# Generating correlated random variables from two different distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose, I want to generate two random variables $X$ and $Y$, Such that $X$ follows $Binomial$ distribution and $Y$ follows $Negative$ $Binomial$ distribution and they have correlation $\rho$.

I cant figure out how can I do this. Here I have taken binomial and negative binomial just for example, basically I was thinking of any two different but known distribution .

Comment: I can't avoid to think in the multivariate Gaussian and that makes me believe that somehow we have to design a covariance matrix between the random variables that help us to tie the marginals into a joint PDF...but no sure about how to proceed...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an ad-hoc way. Center and rescale $X$, $Y$ to zero mean and unit variance. Assume $\rho>0$ (otherwise flip sign of $Y$). Pick $p\in(0,1)$ and pick $x,y$, s.t. $F_X(x)=F_Y(y)=p$. With probability $p$ generate $A\sim X|X\le x$ and $B\sim Y|Y\le y$ and with probability $1-p$ generate $A\sim X|X>x$, $B\sim Y|Y>y$. Tune $p$ so that

$$\rho=E(AB)=2E(X;X\le x)E(Y;Y\le y)$$

---

Here is a clearer way: with probability $p$ use the same uniform $U$ to generate $X$ and $Y$ by inverse transform ($X\sim F_X^{-1}(U)$) and with probability $1-p$ use independent uniforms. $p=0$ is independent case i.e. $\rho=0$. $p=1$ is the strongest coupling possible and highest $\rho_m=E(F_X^{-1}(U)F_Y^{-1}(U))$ - compute it and pick $p=\rho/\rho_m$.

Comment: I am interested about that tuning in particular.
Other wise I just could have generated two uniform $U_1$ and $U_2$ with some correlation $\rho_1$ and took $F^{-1}_X(U_1)$ and $F^{-1}_Y(U_2)$ as my samples.
Intuitively they should be correlated. But I cant say what will be the correlation between them.

Comment: Is it true that if $X$ and $Y$ has correlation $\rho$. And $f$ and $g$ are non-decreasing, then $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ has correlation $\rho$ as well?

Comment: @sub No, it's not true for. Take $f$ and $g$ constant to example. You need to compute (or estimate via Monte Carlo) $\rho_m=E(F_X^{-1}(U)F_Y^{-1}(U))$ for the second method to work with already given "tuning".

Comment: What if the functions are strictly increasing?